# Image gallery display clicked image in new page, slider view

Tags: php, jquery, hyperlink

I have a file with photos stored as hyperlinks called "photos.php" from where the user can click on any photo.
I have an other file called "slider.php" where are stored the photos I refer above displayed in a simple slider with left-right arrows, without auto play.

My question is:
How can I connect those two php files, so if the user click on one photo(hyperlink) from the photos.php, then the slider.php displays the image he clicked on. (For example if he click on photo.php the hyperlink "image3.jpg", the hyperlink moves to slider.php and show "image3.jpg.Then, if he click the right arrow he goes to the next one (image4.jpg) etc. 
I should use a id for each img and through jquery display the clicked image?

Bellow is the code of the two php files:

```
<!--photos.php-->
<div id="gallery">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#"><img src="image1.jpg" width="100" height="150" alt="" /></a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#"><img src="image2.jpg" width="100" height="150" alt="" /></a>
</li> 
<li>
<a href="#"><img src="image3.jpg" width="100" height="150" alt="" /></a>
<li>
<a href="#"><img src="image4.jpg" width="100" height="150" alt="" /></a>
</li> 
</ul>
</div>

<!--slider.php-->
<div id="slider">
<a href="#" class="control_next">></a>
<a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
<ul>
<li><img src="image1.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="image2.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="image3.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="image4.jpg" /></li>
</ul>  
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be something you can do with Bootstrap Carousel, http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

The bulk of the actions you need will happen on the client side, also, you will need to merge the files to get best performance

Comment: To make it more clear, I want the same result with a lightbox like this: [link](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) .
THe only difference is that istead of a pop-up window, I want to open in a new page where will be displayed the clicked image and the navigation arrows to navigate the rest images.